# Retrive data from asset folder in Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I can't insert database in asset folder into my main activity. I get an error when I run this.

I need to place in that colums and that coloums is in names activity.

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static String DB_PATH = "file:///android_asset/bcanew.db";
    private static String DB_NAME = "bcanew.db";
    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
    private Context context;
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "student_names";
    public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
    public static final String COL_2 = "NAME";
    public static final String COL_3 = "CURRENT_CGPA";
    public static final String COL_4 = "ACTIVE_BACKLOGS";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context, Names names, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {

        super(context, String.valueOf(names), factory, version);
    }

    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

        // Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {

        db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public Cursor getData() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor res;
        res = db.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_NAME, null);
        return res;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code..
make method for read file from assets folders.. and return file as string.

```
private String readFile(String fileName, Context context) {
    StringBuilder returnString = new StringBuilder();
    InputStream fIn = null;
    InputStreamReader isr = null;
    BufferedReader input = null;
    try {
        fIn = context.getResources().getAssets().open(fileName);
        isr = new InputStreamReader(fIn);
        input = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line;
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
            returnString.append(line);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (isr != null) isr.close();
            if (fIn != null) fIn.close();
            if (input != null) input.close();
        } catch (Exception e2) {
            e2.getMessage();
        }
    }
    return returnString.toString();
}
```

after that calls method into activity or fragment like this way..

```
        String jsonObject = readFile("wg_sample.json", this); // define file name here define one json file name.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have created an "assets" folder within the same directory as your "res" folder. From the look of your path it looks like you've created some custom other directory.

Create the assets folder under the same directory as your "res" folder. 
Then call the following method:

```
getAssets().open("filename_in_assets_directory");
```

You may have to do:

```
context.getAssets().open("filename_in_assets_directory");
```

If you are calling not from your activity.

Comment: where should i keep assest in my program

Comment: Your assets directory should be under:
YOUR_ANDROID_PROJECT_FOLDER\app\src\main\assets\